# Limiting search results to associated model with Ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I've set up the ability to search pins in my app using ransack gem. I need the index to only render pins that are from the school searched.

EDIT: Added routes.rb and rake routes output

rake routes

```
  pins GET        /pins(.:format)                                   pins#index
                           POST       /pins(.:format)                                   pins#create
                   new_pin GET        /pins/new(.:format)                               pins#new
                  edit_pin GET        /pins/:id/edit(.:format)                          pins#edit
                       pin GET        /pins/:id(.:format)                               pins#show
                           PATCH      /pins/:id(.:format)                               pins#update
                           PUT        /pins/:id(.:format)                               pins#update
                           DELETE     /pins/:id(.:format)                               pins#destroy


search_school_pins GET|POST   /schools/:school_id/pins/search(.:format)         schools/pins#search
               school_pins GET        /schools/:school_id/pins(.:format)                schools/pins#index
                           POST       /schools/:school_id/pins(.:format)                schools/pins#create
            new_school_pin GET        /schools/:school_id/pins/new(.:format)            schools/pins#new
           edit_school_pin GET        /schools/:school_id/pins/:id/edit(.:format)       schools/pins#edit
                school_pin GET        /schools/:school_id/pins/:id(.:format)            schools/pins#show
                           PATCH      /schools/:school_id/pins/:id(.:format)            schools/pins#update
                           PUT        /schools/:school_id/pins/:id(.:format)            schools/pins#update
                           DELETE     /schools/:school_id/pins/:id(.:format)            schools/pins#destroy
         school_classrooms GET        /schools/:school_id/classrooms(.:format)          classrooms#index
                           POST       /schools/:school_id/classrooms(.:format)          classrooms#create
      new_school_classroom GET        /schools/:school_id/classrooms/new(.:format)      classrooms#new
     edit_school_classroom GET        /schools/:school_id/classrooms/:id/edit(.:format) classrooms#edit
          school_classroom GET        /schools/:school_id/classrooms/:id(.:format)      classrooms#show
                           PATCH      /schools/:school_id/classrooms/:id(.:format)      classrooms#update
                           PUT        /schools/:school_id/classrooms/:id(.:format)      classrooms#update
                           DELETE     /schools/:school_id/classrooms/:id(.:format)      classrooms#destroy
   new_school_admin_school GET        /schools/:id/new_school_admin(.:format)           schools#new_school_admin
       create_admin_school POST       /schools/:id/create_admin(.:format)               schools#create_admin
        new_teacher_school GET        /schools/:id/new_teacher(.:format)                schools#new_teacher
     create_teacher_school POST       /schools/:id/create_teacher(.:format)             schools#create_teacher
                   schools POST       /schools(.:format)                                schools#create
               edit_school GET        /schools/:id/edit(.:format)                       schools#edit
                    school GET        /schools/:id(.:format)                            schools#show
                           PATCH      /schools/:id(.:format)                            schools#update
                           PUT        /schools/:id(.:format)                            schools#update
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 resources :reflections
 resources :pins
 resources :leads

 devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)  


resources :schools, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update] do
resources :pins, module: :schools do
  collection do match 'search' => 'pins#search', via: [:get, :post], as:    :search
  end
end
 resources :classrooms
 member do
   get 'new_school_admin'
   post 'create_admin'
 end
 member do

   get 'new_teacher'
   post 'create_teacher'
 end
end
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}

devise_scope :user do
  get '/signout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :signout

  get 'register' => 'registrations#new_school'
  post 'register'  => 'registrations#create_school'
end

get 'activate', to: 'users#activate'
patch 'activate_user', to: 'users#activate_user'

# devise_for :users
root to: "application#index"
get "about" => "application#about"
get "terms" => "application#terms"
resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update]

end
```

Associations:

User.rb

```
has_many :pins
```

Pin.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

School.rb

```
has_many :users
has_many :classrooms
has_many :pins, through: :users
```

pins_controller.rb

```
def search
  index
  render :index
  authorize @pins
end

def index
  @q = Pin.search(params[:q])
  @pins = @q.result(distinct: true).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10 )
  respond_with(@pins)
  authorize @pins
end
```

pins/index.html.erb

This block works fine but shows all pins on the data base and not just the ones that belong to a school.

```
<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
<% end %>
```

I tried and it gave me an error message in Pins#index

```
@school.pins.each
undefined method `pins' for nil:NilClass
```

schools/show.html.erb

This is the search form

```
 <%= f.search_field :user_name_cont, placeholder: "Search...", class: "form-control" %>
 <% end %>
```

here's the search feature in routes.rb

```
 resources :pins do
   collection do 
     match 'search' => 'pins#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
   end
end
```

EDIT: Pin Schema

```
  create_table "pins", force: true do |t|
   t.integer  "user_id"
   t.text     "question"
   t.text     "question2"
   t.text     "question3"
   t.text     "question4"
   t.text     "question5"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.text     "question1"
   t.integer  "classroom_id"
   t.string   "sad"
   t.string   "mad"
   t.string   "brave"
   t.string   "embarrassed"
   t.string   "sorry"
   t.string   "frustrated"
   t.string   "left_out"
   t.string   "hurt"
   t.string   "confused"
   t.string   "worried"
   t.string   "proud"
   t.string   "other"
   t.integer  "sash_id"
   t.integer  "level",        default: 0
   end
```

What do I need to do to limit the pins that show up to only the ones that belong to that school?

Comment: How is the variable `@school` being populated in your `search` method?

Comment: I guess that it's not being populated. When I add this  @school = School.find(params[:school]) to the search method, it doesn't change the result. When I add it to the index (in pins controller) I get an error that it can't find the school id. This is because the index isn't apart of the school. Any ideas?

Comment: My experience of rails is also a bit limited, but I don't see a place where you're actually limiting your search criteria to a specific school, nor do I see a place where the school is a parameter of anything. Have you tried, in the rails console, writing `pin = Pin.first` and then `pin.school`? If this returns `nil` or a NoMethodError, then the Pin data type doesn't know about schools. What does your pin migration look like?

Comment: Yea you are right, there it returns nil. This makes sense thought because school has many pins through users.

Comment: If your pin doesn't have a field for school, how do you plan to limit a collection of pins by school? (That's not a snarky rhetorical question :-) ) I may need to see your schema.

Comment: Ok so I added my pin schema. (No offense taken) In my school show.html I'm able to call @school.pins.count and it only counts the pins for that school so I was thinking it would still work in this case.. but it's not. Maybe I need to create a join table here for pins?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79365/discussion-between-user3787971-and-pgblu).